# Issues with <strong> and <h4> on hover

Tags: html, css, hover

when I hover over my h4 tag in the table, everything works properly. However, when I hover over the strong tag that is located inside the h4 element, the strong tag obtains the same hover as the h4 tag.

I have a table element and each td element is structured as shown below:

```
<td>
  <a>
    <div>
      <h4>
        ...<strong>...</strong>...
      </h4>
    </div>
  </a>
</td>
```

Here is the CSS that affects the elements in the table.

```
h4 {
  font-weight: 100;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 12px 0px;
  color: black;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

a:visited {
  color: white;
  background-color: none;
}

strong :hover {
  background: none !important;
  background-color: transparent !important;
}

/*Used for the gradient on hover for the background*/

.itemTrue > a > div :hover {
  color: white;
  background: #e4e4e4;
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  #e4e4e4 0%, #295534 73%, #1d3923 88%, #000000 100%);
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#e4e4e4), color-stop(73%,#295534), color-stop(88%,#1d3923), color-stop(100%,#000000));
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  #e4e4e4 0%,#295534 73%,#1d3923 88%,#000000 100%);
  background: -o-linear-gradient(top,  #e4e4e4 0%,#295534 73%,#1d3923 88%,#000000 100%);
  background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,  #e4e4e4 0%,#295534 73%,#1d3923 88%,#000000 100%);
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom,  #e4e4e4 0%,#295534 73%,#1d3923 88%,#000000 100%);
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#e4e4e4', endColorstr='#000000',GradientType=0 );
}
```

What I am trying to do is basically keep the strong tag's background as blank on hover while still having the gradient appear as the background for the div/h4 on hover.

Everything works perfectly when nothing is being hovered over.

Answer (score 11):

You have to connect the selectors `strong` and `:hover` in your CSS:

```
strong:hover
```

in your code it's

```
strong :hover
```

Comment: Wow, I can't believe that  I did something so dumb. =(

Thank you Sebsemillia. =)

Comment: hehe, might happen at a late hour.. ;) and you have the same error with `.itemTrue > a > div :hover`..